# Keras StringLookup: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to Keras and Tensorflow. Yesterday, I came across an error which is the following:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

The block of code that gave this error is:

```
for name, inpt in inputs.items():

    if inpt.dtype == tf.string:
        lookup = layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=np.unique(train[name]))
```

Here, inputs is a dictionary which contains Tensors of each column of the train dataset. All have the dtype of either `float32` or `string`.

In the above code, I'm trying to fetch only the string dtypes but it's giving me the error that cannot compare `str` & `float` which has made me confused as the code should fetch only the `string` dtypes features.

Where am I doing wrong? Can you tell me?

Comment: Please check the exact similar logic code mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#mixed_data_types) in this document which may help you to solve this error. Let us know if the issue still persists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the features in  has None values. None are considered as float as np.nan. Drop them or try to replace None values with "unknown" ,...etc.

```
train.dropna(inplace=True)
```

I'm new to Tensorflow. Once I find better solution, I will post it here asap.